# Linking silicon webserver with libmicrohttpd backend

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, freebsd

I'm trying to compile the silicon webserver hello world [example](http://siliconframework.org/docs/hello_world.html) on FreeBSD 10.2 RELEASE using clang++38. The framework uses c++14. I have installed libmicrohttpd.

When I try to compile the program using

```
clang++38 -O2 -Wall -std=c++14 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lmicrohttpd -o sws01 sws01.cpp
```

I get the error

```
In file included from sws01.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/silicon/backends/mhd.hh:158:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MHD_http_unescape'
    value.resize(MHD_http_unescape(&value[0]));
```

The sws01.cpp:

```
#include <silicon/api.hh>
#include <silicon/backends/mhd.hh>
#include "symbols.hpp"

using namespace sl;
using namespace s;

auto hello_api = http_api(
        GET / _hello = [](){ return D(_message = "Hello from Silicon Webserver!"); }
);

int main() {
    sl::mhd_json_serve(hello_api, 9876);
}
```

I tried to apply this SO [thread](http://siliconframework.org/docs/hello_world.html) answer but `-Wl` and specifying `/usr/local/lib/libmicrohttpd.a` like

```
clang++38 -O2 -Wall -std=c++14 -I/usr/local/include /usr/local/lib/libmicrohttpd.a -o sws01 sws01.cpp
```

did not work either.

Works on os x using xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the libmicrohttpd-server that ships with the FreeBSD ports-system is ver. 0.9.37 and libmicrohttpd.so does not have MHD_http_unescape() but libmicrohttpd.a does. The newest is currently 0.9.48. Replacing the ports-version with this solves my compilation issue.